# Why does Shader not work in html5 module but works in desktop app?

Tags: opengl, gwt, libgdx, shader

Following this tutorial https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Meshes-Lesson-1 on rendering Meshes. It works fine on Desktop Application, but deployed to html5 its all black and spams:

> .WebGL-000001FC218B3370]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

Why does it not work? I am not using an array in the shader.

Im using this simple shader which is just supposed to render position and color of a vertex:

Vertex shader

```
    //our attributes
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;

//our camera matrix
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

//send the color out to the fragment shader
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    vColor = a_color;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

//input from vertex shader
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Rendering like this

```
triangle.mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18 / NUM_COMPONENTS);
```

**Edit**

My vertex specification

```
public static final int MAX_TRIS = 1;
public static final int MAX_VERTS = MAX_TRIS * 3;

// ...

protected float[] verts = new float[MAX_VERTS * NUM_COMPONENTS];

mesh = new Mesh(true, MAX_VERTS, 0,
                    new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 2, "a_position"),
                    new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked, 4, "a_color"));

float c = color.toFloatBits();

idx = 0;

verts[idx++] = coordinates[0].x;
verts[idx++] = coordinates[0].y;
verts[idx++] = c;

//top left vertex
verts[idx++] = coordinates[1].x;
verts[idx++] = coordinates[1].y;
verts[idx++] = c;

//bottom right vertex
verts[idx++] = coordinates[2].x;
verts[idx++] = coordinates[2].y;
verts[idx++] = c;

mesh.setVertices(verts);
```

My draw call

```
public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(false);
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

        shaderProgram.begin();  // shaderprogram contains vertex and fragment shader
        shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", world.renderer.getCam().combined);
        for (Triangle triangle : triangles) {
            triangle.mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18 / NUM_COMPONENTS);

        }
        shaderProgram.end();
        Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
    }
```

Comment: The error message is not related to the shader code! It means that there are not enough vertex attributes in the vertex array buffer! It means that the 3rd parameter *count* specifies more vertices, then that number of vertices in the buffer.

Comment: Thank you, do you have an idea how that can happen? Because on desktop everything works just fine (open gl).

Comment: Of course, there is a bug in your code. Probably a small mistake when porting the code. But I can't tell you what, without knowing the vertex specification and draw call.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Please check out my edit! I added how I create the vertices and my render call.

Comment: It should be `VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"` rather than `VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 2, "a_position"`, isn't it?

Comment: I think not, I render in 2D

Comment: But each vertex in the buffer has 3 components, isn't it? It has to be the tuple size of the vertex coordinate.

Comment: If you render a singe triangle with 3 vertices, then it has to be `shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3` rather than `18 / NUM_COMPONENTS`

Comment: Yes, the 18 was the issue! I hardcoded the value while testing and then forgot about it. I changed it to 9 (because 3 components per vertex) and now it works on html5 module too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

> .WebGL-000001FC218B3370]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

means that there are not enough vertex attributes in the vertex array buffer.
It means that the 3rd parameter *count* specifies more vertices, than that number of vertices in the buffer.

If you've a vertex buffer with 3 vertices, then *count* has to be 3, respectively `9 / NUM_COMPONENTS` since the tuple size of a vertex coordinate is 3 and the array has a size of 9 elements:

<s>`triangle.mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 18 / NUM_COMPONENTS);`</s>
`triangle.mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9 / NUM_COMPONENTS);`